# Output only csv lines if column increment is 2

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that I would like to filter. The output I need would be only to output the lines if the increment is not equal to 2. In the csv file below, I would like to compare the first line with the second line, if the increment is 2, check line 3 vs line 2, and so on. If the increment is not equal to 2, output the line. I'm looking at the 3rd cloumn values

```
L1,is,2.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:07:46
L1,is,4.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:09:46
L1,is,6.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:11:46
L1,is,8.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:13:46
L1,is,10.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:15:46
L1,is,2.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:19:49
L1,is,4.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:21:49
L1,is,6.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:23:49
L1,is,8.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:25:49
L1,is,10.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:27:49
L1,is,16.2,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:34:02
L1,is,18.2,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:36:02
L1,is,20.2,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:38:02
L1,is,2.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,bridge,21:45:26
L1,is,4.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,bridge,21:47:26
L1,is,6.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,bridge,21:49:26
```

So only lines 5,10,13 and 16 would output to page.
I'm stuck on this and would appreciate any help or direction on where to look.
Thanks

Comment: @CBroe - I started with reading the file, then looking at the array keys to determine what I need to compare it to, and that is where I got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is not too big, you can load it into memory directly, like this:

```
$data = array_map(function($row)
{
   return explode(',', $row);
}, file('/path/to/file.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
$result     = [];
$increment  = 2;
$delta      = 1E-13;
for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++)
{
   if(abs($data[$i][2]-$data[$i-1][2]-$increment)>$delta)
   {
      $result[$i] = $data[$i];
   }
}
```

-since your column holds floats, safe comparison on equality will be using precision delta.

Your data will be gathered in `$result` array, so you can output it like

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
   echo(join(',', $row).PHP_EOL);
}
```

-or, else, do not store rows inside `$result` array (if you will need them no longer) and use first cycle to output your rows.

*Edit*:
Sample above will work in PHP>=5.4 For PHP 5.3 you should replace array definition to

```
$result     = array();
```

and if you have even older PHP version, like 5.2, then callback inside `array_map()` should be rewritten with using `create_function()`

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting a error "syntax error unexpected '[' in line 5. Thanks again for the help

Comment: For PHP <5.4 you should replace array definition (I've updated)

Comment: Thanks it works, except I'm getting exactly the next line I want, instead of line 5 I'm getting line 6.

Comment: Strange. For your text I got 5, 10 and 13 rows (seems to be ok)

Comment: seems I'm missing something, but I'll work it through, seems its skipping the first line. Thanks again you have helped alot!!

Comment: The code seems to stop before the end of the file, thus not giving line 16 as output?

Comment: @kirchner20 got that. My point is about PHP indexes (and they start from 0) while you're about native numbers (i.e. from 1). So - it seems we're saying about same things?

Comment: no sorry, looks like its not outputting the last line? As line 16 is the last index it should also in theory be added? Or am I not understanding? Thanks

Comment: No. My point was about misunderstanding indexes. 16-th line has nothing to do with that: it's increment is exactly 2: `6.0-4.0` - so I don't know why you're thinking it should be included

Comment: Ok got it! "Face Palm" Thanks For all the help!